# Send email on Job Dispatched from WP e-commerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, e-commerce

I sell a product using WP e-commerce that is downloadable only after I check some information that the customer sends me. After checking the information I would like to go to the WordPress dashboard, change the order status to "Job Dispatched", and have that trigger a new email to the customer with instructions on what to do next.

Any ideas or experience with attaching some trigger event or option to the "Job Dispatched" status change?

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old the answer might be useful to someone...
You can a trigger this event with the wpsc_update_purchase_log_status hook.

```
function purchaseLogStatusEvent( $id, $status, $old_status, $purchase_log ) {
    /************************
    status codes:
      1: Incomplete Sale
      2: Order Received
      3: Accepted Payment
      4: Job Dispatched
      5: Closed Order
      6: Payment Declined
    ************************/
    if ($status==4){
        //do your magic
    }

}
add_action('wpsc_update_purchase_log_status', 'purchaseLogStatusEvent', 9, 4 );
```